# Change or swap fit skills damage with others

Tags: ring-fit-adventure

--QUESTION--

Is there any way to modify/swap fit skill stats with others? For example, can I swap damage stat for overhead arm twist (90 damage) with overhead press (30 damage)?

Thanks

--CONTEXT--

As you progress, you will acquire different fit skills. These exercises have different stats for damage, cooldown, and range. You start the game with squat with 30 damage; later, you can unlock stronger squat with 360 damage. Sounds good.

People have different physique. For some, squat is very physically challenging, while for the others are not. Also, some people might not be able to perform specific exercises due to various condition such as injury, obesity, etc.

I have my preferred set of exercises that I'm comfortable with. These exercises provide good challenge and does not mess with my body (bow pulls hurt my wrist and forearm so much). But these exercises are too weak in term of damage compared to other exercises. If I forced myself to get along with it, fighting boss with low damage output took forever and somehow took the fun away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't swap damage values on skills, however do you have the ability to gain upgraded versions of old skills later in the game, making them useful again with their increased damage output.